# NSolve non-analytic function

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

```
l1 = 0.167;
l2 = 0.078596;
θ = π/18;

NSolve[θ == ArcTan[(1/Sqrt[k] Sin[Sqrt[k] l1] + 
            l2 Cos[Sqrt[k] l1])/(-l2 Sqrt[k] Sin[Sqrt[k] l1] + 
            Cos[Sqrt[k] l1])], k]
```

How to get the solution of the following above?

Comment: suggest you plot `θ - ArcTan`, you'll see you have many roots. `FindRoot` gives you one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may infinitely many solutions.  This will find some, if you limit the range on `k`:

```
Block[{θ = π/18, l1 = 0.167, l2 = 0.078596},
 NSolve[θ == 
    ArcTan[(1/Sqrt[k] Sin[Sqrt[k] l1] + 
        l2 Cos[Sqrt[k] l1])/(-l2 Sqrt[k] Sin[Sqrt[k] l1] + 
        Cos[Sqrt[k] l1])] && 0 < k < 10000, k]
 ]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

```
(* {{k -> 421.101}, {k -> 1494.26}, {k -> 3266.71}, {k -> 5745.09}, {k -> 8930.65}} *)
```

There is a negative root that is hard for `NSolve` to find.  If we use `FindRoot`, it's simple:

```
Block[{θ = π/18, l1 = 0.167, l2 = 0.078596},
 FindRoot[θ == 
   ArcTan[(1/Sqrt[k] Sin[Sqrt[k] l1] + 
       l2 Cos[Sqrt[k] l1])/(-l2 Sqrt[k] Sin[Sqrt[k] l1] + 
       Cos[Sqrt[k] l1])], {k, -50}]
 ]
(*  {k -> -21.7265 + 0. I}  *)
```

You can see one problem is that negative values of `k` make the function values complex.  Note that I killed the corresponding `NSolve` command with the restriction `-50 < k < 0` after several minutes when it had reached 6+GB of memory usage.

Comment: In `FindRoot` use `l1 = 0.167\`15, l2 = 0.078596\`15` and `WorkingPrecision->15` to remove complex result.

Comment: @BobHanlon Neat.  I didn't expect that.  Usually once complex numbers arise, the stick around, even if the imaginary part comes out zero.

Comment: I just ran your codes,but a problem occurred when I plug theta = pi/18 *10. Basically, I want to get the array of K value when theta is from pi/18*1, pi/18*2, ..., pi/18*18.

Comment: @Lawerance Since `ArcTan` for real arguments is "always in the range -Pi/2 to Pi/2" (docs), there should be no solutions when theta is `Pi/18 * 10`, which is what I get.